# Glassfish and Tomcat in same server machine and hosting more than one site on both?

Tags: java, tomcat, dns, glassfish

I have a tomcat 6.0 web server on my server machine.now i created a glassfish server on the same machine. for avoid port conflict i just change glassfish port to 8081. now how can i access my web applications on both glassfish and tomcat from different DNS name.

Comment: First, why do you need to Glassfish _and_ Tomcat? Second why Tomcat 6? This is ancient... Third, you need to use virtual hosts. If you want to access them both on port 80 you need to run Apache as a reverse proxy with a virtual host for each DNS name proxying a different server.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your DNS/server setup.

- You could use Apache and reverse proxies:

  ```
      <VirtualHost *>
      ProxyPreserveHost On

      # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
      # List of application servers:
      # Usage:
      # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
      # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
      # Example: 
      ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8081/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8081/

      ServerName glassfish.server
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *>
      ProxyPreserveHost On

      # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
      # List of application servers:
      # Usage:
      # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
      # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
      # Example: 
      ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

      ServerName tomcat.server
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Or you could use your DNS. I'm afraid I can't help you with that.